# Name for a category

Tags: notation, category-theory, terminology

Is there any name or notation for this category?

Let $U$ be a set. By "function" I will mean a function $U\rightarrow U$.

- objects are functions;
- morphisms from a function $A$ to a function $B$ are such functions $f$ that $y=A(x)\Rightarrow f(y)=B(f(x))$ for every $x,y\in U$.

Comment: This is related to http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/arrow+category

Comment: You should specify the domain and codomain of the functions, and why you can apply $f$ to both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: You have not defined a category. As @StefanH notes, it's not clear why you can apply $f$ to both $y$ and to $x$.

Comment: For simplicity let limit both domains and codomains of all functions to some set $U$.

Comment: Instead of writing a comment you should edit this remark into your post so people become aware of your edit. Do you mean that for each function, domain=codomain, or that $U$ is domain and codomain globally?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be the category with a single object $U$ and having as morphisms all functions $U\to U$, and consider the monoid $(\mathbb{N},+)$ as a category in the standard way. Then the category you described can be viewed as the functor category $Funct(\mathbb{N},\mathcal{U})$. Any functor $\mathbb{N}\to\mathcal{U}$ is arises from and is determined by where it takes the arrow generating the monoid $\mathbb{N}$, so you can think of the objects of this category as functions $U\to U$. Any natural transformation between two such functors (i.e. functions $A$ and $B$) arises from and determines a function $f\colon U\to U$ satisfying the equation you asked for.

You can get quite similar categories as functor categories of some kind or another. For example, if $\mathcal{C}$ is the category with two objects $A$ and $B$ and one non-trivial arrow $f\colon A\to B$, then $Funct(\mathcal{C},\mathrm{Set})$ is a category where the objects are essentially functions between sets and morphisms are pairs of functions making the obvious square commute.